# Dropping container with RabbitMQ in Docker

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I try to start a Docker container with RabbitMQ, as a result, the image is downloaded, but the container does not start. I get the following message in the logs:

```
error: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS is set but deprecated
error: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER is set but deprecated
error: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST is set but deprecated
error: RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE is set but deprecated
error: deprecated environment variables detected
```

This problem appeared recently, before that everything worked fine and started.

This is my docker-compose rabbit:

```
rabbit:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    hostname: "rabbit"
    environment:
        RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: 'SWQOKODSQALRPCLNMEQGW'
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: 'user'
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: 'bitnami'
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: '/'
    ports:
        - "15672:15672"
        - "5672:5672"
    labels:
        NAME: "rabbitmq"    
    networks:
        - postgres
```

Comment: From the [official rabbitmq dockerhub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq?tab=description): "***Environment Variables** ... **WARNING:** As of RabbitMQ 3.9, all of the docker-specific variables listed below are deprecated and no longer used. Please use a configuration file instead; visit rabbitmq.com/configure to learn more about the configuration file. For a starting point, the 3.8 images will print out the config file it generated from supplied environment variables. ... - `RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS` ... - `RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER`*"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The latest stable docker image for RabbitMQ (3.9) has been recently updated and the official image page says:

```
As of RabbitMQ 3.9, all of the docker-specific variables listed below are deprecated and no longer used.
```

I have resolved the issue in following way:

1. Create a rabbitmq.conf file in the same folder where docker compose
   file is present
2. Put the variables in there following guidelines and naming convention from [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-items). Something like:

   ```
   default_vhost = /
   default_user = user
   default_pass = bitnami
   ```
3. In docker compose file, instead of an **environment** section put a **volumes** section and mounted the rabbitmq.conf file to proper path (depending on OS, follow [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#customise-environment)). For linux container it will be like:

   ```
   rabbit:
       image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
       hostname: "rabbit"
       volumes:
         - "./rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf"
       ports:
         - "15672:15672"
         - "5672:5672"
       labels:
         NAME: "rabbitmq"    
       networks:
         - postgres
   ```

Comment: This is probably better than my answer, since it addresses the actual error instead of reverting back to the version when it worked. However, the whole reason it came up is because we were using 3-management, which is simply bad practice for an evolving project.

So I guess I would add to yours that it'd be worth doing 3.9-management once the problem is resolved to avoid future breaking changes being added from the outside. No idea if they plan a 3.10 before moving on to 4.0, and they certainly could change the way this is done again.

Answer (score 9):

You should use the following environment varibles:

```
DEFAULT_VHOST=/
DEFAULT_USER=user1
DEFAULT_PASS=pass1
```

see https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html for more information.

Or use other versions of rabbitMQ like 3.8:

```
rabbitmq:3.8-management
```

Answer (score 8):

The line

```
image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
```

Basically (I think) gets the latest stable version of Rabbit, which is 3.9, which has deprecated those variables. If you wish to keep using the latest version of rabbit, you must use a configuration file. Seeing as how you've probably been using 3.8 up until this point, I imagine that's more work than it's worth. You can use 3.8 instead by changing the line to:

```
image: "rabbitmq:3.8-management"
```

The variables are not deprecated in this version and will not throw those errors.

Answer (score 0):

If someone uses only `Dockerfile`, add your config in this same folder and add this line to your `Dockerfile`:

`COPY ./rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf`

Comment: this would expose credentials into docker layers - bad idea