# Docker Container with RabbitMQ crashing

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

First of all, this seems like a similar issue as posted here: [Dropping container with RabbitMQ in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68600215/dropping-container-with-rabbitmq-in-docker)

However, the thread seems inactive after a few days and I would love to ask questions to the only provided answer, but my reputation isn't high enough to do so. I'd also like to try to provide a few more details. Basically, I have a publicly hosted server that I recently tried to push some changes to, but the gitlab deployment failed. The change was extremely minor as far as the backend was concerned (literally just an added variable), and when I tried to undo the change, I received the same error from the docker:

```
error: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS is set but deprecated
error: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER is set but deprecated
error: RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE is set but deprecated
error: deprecated environment variables detected
```

I was never able to reproduce this locally. It seems like upon rebooting or recompiling, RabbitMQ has started giving these errors on the server. I'm not familiar with RabbitMQ, but my guess is that they've recently switched this from a warning to an error, thus causing my server to crash when it redeployed. My docker-compose.yml's rabbit section:

```
rabbitmq:
image: rabbitmq:3-management
environment:
  RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: secret
  RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: [REDACTED]
  RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: [REDACTED]
networks:
  - backend
ports:
  - 15672:15672
  - 5672:5672
```

The response to the other thread suggested to use these variables instead:

```
DEFAULT_VHOST=/
DEFAULT_USER=
DEFAULT_PASS=
```

And provided this link: https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html

But this answer implies that you very simply have to replace the deprecated variables with the one he listed within docker compose. His link provides no clarification on this, but instead provides a different solution which is to use a rabbitmq.conf file. Moreover, using them in place of the old variables just in the docker compose causes a login error locally:

> rabbitmq_1  | PLAIN login refused: user '' attempted to log in with a blank password,
> which is prohibited by the internal authN backend. To use TLS/x509 certificate-based authentication, see the rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl plugin and configure the client to use the EXTERNAL authentication mechanism. Alternatively change the password for the user to be non-blank.

Where did he come up with this answer, is it really as simple as swapping to a non-deprecated set of variables?

If a docker needs a rabbitmq.conf to compile, where would I put the file? I do not have one locally and the website mentions /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf, but that seems to only be the case if it's not run in a docker. I also don't have this file locally, where the docker runs fine.

What about RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE? The website doesn't seem to show an alternative for it, nor did the responder.

Is there still a method run a rabbit docker using docker-compose alone? Or even a method to forcefully allow the use of deprecated variables in the meantime, so that my server runs again?

I would like to provide more info, but I'm not sure what else to share without risking sharing sensitive information. Please let me know what other info could be of use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Rabbitmq version 3.9 has indeed deprecated those variables, and the line `image: rabbitmq:3-management` caused it to grab version 3.9. I changed the line to `image: rabbitmq:3.8-management`, which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following environment varibles:

```
DEFAULT_VHOST=/
DEFAULT_USER=user1
DEFAULT_PASS=pass1
```

see https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html for more information.

Or use other versions of rabbitMQ like 3.8:

```
rabbitmq:3.8-management
```